# Carrinho de compras em smarty

Tags: php, template

Estou desenvolvendo um projeto universitário em que tenho que desenvolver um site web. Estou a usar smarty para a organização do código.
Trata-se de um site de vendas e para tal estou a desenvolver um carrinho de compras, e é aqui que estou com algumas dificuldades...
Adicionei um ficheiro php com o seguinte código:

```
  include_once('../../config/init.php');
  include_once ($BASE_DIR . 'database/events.php');


  if (!isset($_SESSION['cart']))
    $_SESSION['cart'] = array();

  $events = array();

  foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as $id => $quantity) {
    $event = selectID($id);

    $event['quantity']=$quantity;
    $events[] = $event;

  }

  $types = getAllTypes();
  $smarty->assign('types', $types);
  $smarty->assign('events', $events);

  $smarty->display('shop/list_cart.tpl');
```

Seguido de um ficheiro smarty .tpl:

```
{include file='common/header.tpl'}

<section id="cart">
  <h2>Shopping Cart</h2>

  <table>
    {foreach from=$events key=id item=event}
      <tr>

        <td>{$event.preco}€</td>
        <td>{$event.nome}</td>



      </tr>
    {/foreach}
  </table>

  <form action="action_checkout.php">
    <input type="submit" value="Checkout">
  </form>

</section>


{include file='common/footer.tpl'}
```

No entanto quando corro o programa surge um erro onde diz que preço e nome não são reconhecidos... Penso que o erro esteja no `foreach` do template, mas não estou conseguindo perceber o que devo alterar.

Comment: Existe uma forma certa de inserir o código na pergunta. Dá uma olhada no tour e na parte de como fazer perguntas. Vejo que um usuário havia corrigido seu post, mas não se sabe porque a correção foi revertida.

Comment: no TPL d um <pre> seguido de um  {$event|@print_r} por favor